# Emfile error running nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Can't seem to get nodemon up and running.

It works when using just node (node app.js) but when using nodemon (nodemon app.js) the following Emfile error is returned:

```
20 Nov 12:26:33 - [nodemon] v0.7.10
20 Nov 12:26:33 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
20 Nov 12:26:33 - [nodemon] watching: /home/ramzi/ST/swaggertrack
20 Nov 12:26:33 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
Express server listening on port 80
mongo is connected
EMFILE: Watching too many files.
EMFILE: Watching too many files.
EMFILE: Watching too many files.
EMFILE: Watching too many files.
```

Has anyone got any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: `EMFILE` happens when your process opened too many files at once. How many files/subdirectories do you have in your folder? Also, edit [your .nodemonignore file](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#ignoring-files) with the files or directories you don't want to watch, this should fix the issue.

Comment: Had to reinstall node, npm and nodemom and also re cloned my git repo. It then worked so think it was due to some sort of library duplication.

Answer (score 0):

If you update to nodemon@1.0.12 (currently latest) it will warn out if there's too many files being watched (i.e. > 25,000 files - a rough arbitrary number I chose). If you don't get that warning, it's possible it's your script.

Happy to help debug (assuming you're on the latest version) at http://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/new